# WP7 -- Open Files With the Default App?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, windows-phone

I created a Windows Phone 7 app that downloads files from my server and stores them in isolated storage, but I'm having trouble finding any info about how to open files with other (default) apps.

For instance, if I download a .psd file to isolated storage, what C# call do I have to write to make the system open said file in any available app that can read it? This can be done on other platforms (iOS, and Android), but I haven't found any literature on the subject for Windows Phone 7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At this point, Windows Phone does not let you use any file associations. So, for example, if you download a PDF, even if the Adobe Reader is installed, you cannot launch the application with the file path as the parameter (yet, you can get the full file path from the Isolated Storage). Your best bet would be having the online source available and passing it to a `WebBrowserTask`, that, if an association is present, will automatically open the appropriate application.

Answer (score 1):

beacause windows phone 7 only allows your own app to read your isolated storage !you can't read any other app's Isolated storage

Comment: So, you're saying that it's not possible to open a file downloaded from the Internet on Windows Phone 7? What about if I downloaded a picture (png/jpg...), or word document, or any other file type that the phone can natively view. How would i get the system to display it for me?

Comment: you can use "Chooser" just like CameraCaptureTask,PhotoChooserTask ... in this namespace" using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks; "